# Inserting formula into plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What's a standard way to insert formula into `Plot`?

My plot is below. I'd like to have the formula of the plot nicely formatted and inserted into plot. `TraditionalForm` looks OK, but it puts the formula in one line, whereas I want a two-line fraction.

```
Plot[{1, (\[CapitalDelta] - 1)^(\[CapitalDelta] - 
   1)/(\[CapitalDelta] - 2)^\[CapitalDelta]}, {\[CapitalDelta], 3, 6},
  PlotRange -> {0, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Dashing[.02], Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[CapitalDelta]", "\[Lambda]"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this could get you started?

```
Plot[{1,(\[CapitalDelta]-1)^(\[CapitalDelta]-1)/(\[CapitalDelta]-2)^\[CapitalDelta]}, 
{\[CapitalDelta],3,6},PlotRange->{0,4},
PlotStyle->{Dashing[.02],Thick},AxesLabel->{"\[CapitalDelta]","\[Lambda]"},
Epilog->Inset[Style[
   HoldForm@@MakeExpression@MakeBoxes@TraditionalForm[(\[CapitalDelta]-1)^
   (\[CapitalDelta]-1)/(\[CapitalDelta]-2)^\[CapitalDelta]],10]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like `HoldForm @@ MakeExpression@MakeBoxes@TraditionalForm` is the magic sequence I needed to get the formula formatted as fraction

Comment: @Yaroslav: There is probably a more elegant way - this is just the first thing that worked, from what I quickly tried.

Comment: You can also replace `HoldForm@@MakeExpression@` with just `DisplayForm@`

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for being late :D. I mostly use a simplified version of Leonid's answer.  Not sure if it is general enough for any purpose, but certainly works here.

```
Plot[{1, (\[CapitalDelta] - 1)^(\[CapitalDelta] - 
      1)/(\[CapitalDelta] - 2)^\[CapitalDelta]}, {\[CapitalDelta], 3, 
  6}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Dashing[.02], Thick}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[CapitalDelta]", "\[Lambda]"},
```

> **Epilog -> Inset[HoldForm@TraditionalForm[**

```
   (\[CapitalDelta] - 1)^(\[CapitalDelta] - 1)/
   (\[CapitalDelta] - 2)^\[CapitalDelta]]]]
```

[image]

Or use **Epilog -> Inset[Panel@HoldForm@TraditionalForm...** for a nice box around the function:

[image]